# How can I add a red circle to the right top corner

Tags: android, xml

I have a cardview that should show a circle when some update is available.
Cardview->

```cs
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_black_48"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top | right"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Circle

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
  <solid
      android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
  <size android:width="60dp"
       android:height="60dp" />
</shape>
```

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KUou.png)

I want the circle to be on the top right corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `LinearLayout` in `CardView`. It would be okay.

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/pink"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top | right"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Update:**

Set the background of the `ImageView` to make the image full screen. The image i set before does not match the full screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="15dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"           
        android:background="@drawable/pink"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top | right"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: yeah but i want it to go to the corner something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHfPb.png

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it. Set the image of `ImageView` to make it full screen would fix this issue.